# Is it possible to make page transition(similar to a PowerPoint presentation) in pdf files using iText without database connectivity?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

Recently i saw in iText website that we can make page transition for pdf file similar to powerpoint presentation (i.e)dissolving, glittering the pages and so on. But they give few examples regarding that also they make databse connection for each example. I want to make it without database connection. I'm also include the link for your reference
              [iText page transition](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=106)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for this task it's very simple and easy. Just we have to add the following code to get various designs in pdf slide show

```
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
        writer.setTransition(new PdfTransition(PdfTransition.DGLITTER, 2));
        writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageModeFullScreen);
        writer.setDuration(2);
```

Instead of DGLITTER you can add various designs.